# opencv with ros kinetic

Tags: opencv, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm trying to use opencv with ros kinetic. I can run catkin build successfully, but when the method `cv::imwrite("image", cv_ptr->image, compression_params);` is called, my node dies.

The console shows the following output:

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (could not find a writer for the specified extension) in imwrite_, file /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.2.0/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp, line 531
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.2.0/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:531: error: (-2) could not find a writer for the specified extension in function imwrite_

[caltab_detector_node-2] process has died [pid 30212, exit code -6, cmd /home/benny/xenial_ws/devel/lib/caltab_detector/caltab_detector_node caltab_detector_node/image_in:=/webcam/image_raw __name:=caltab_detector_node __log:=/home/benny/.ros/log/2ef1c64e-07d0-11e7-8d74-5c514fc42bc4/caltab_detector_node-2.log].
log file: /home/benny/.ros/log/2ef1c64e-07d0-11e7-8d74-5c514fc42bc4/caltab_detector_node-2*.log
```

In my C++ node I'm including `<opencv2/opencv.hpp>`. Is this the correct include for ros kinetic?

My package.xml:

```
<depend>roscpp</depend>
<depend>cv_bridge</depend>
<depend>sensor_msgs</depend>
```

My CMakeLists.xml:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(caltab_detector)

## Make sure HALCONROOT is set
if(NOT DEFINED ENV{HALCONROOT})
  message( FATAL_ERROR "PLEASE SET HALCONROOT" )
endif()

add_definitions(-std=c++11)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp cv_bridge sensor_msgs)
find_package(OpenCV 3 REQUIRED)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include $ENV{HALCONROOT}/include $ENV{HALCONROOT}/include/halconcpp
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp cv_bridge sensor_msgs
)

include_directories(include $ENV{HALCONROOT}/include $ENV{HALCONROOT}/include/halconcpp  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

link_directories($ENV{HALCONROOT}/lib/$ENV{HALCONARCH})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_node src/caltab_detector_node.cpp)

add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}_node ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_node
   halconcpp
   halcon
   X11
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
   ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}
)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256850/opencv-with-ros-kinetic/) by [bennypi](https://answers.ros.org/users/8396/bennypi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2017-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As The exception says: no writer For File Type. Acutally no File type in your case. Make "image" an e.g. "image.png" to tell opencv to save the File in png format

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2017-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2